# In Google Groups, what does the gray number to the right of Original Poster in the Topics list mean?

Tags: google-groups

In Google Groups, I am seeing a gray number to the right of the original poster of a thread. It is typically +1, +2, and the number is less than the number of total posts.

In each line:

```
[star] [discussion double quotes] [Thread title] [number of posts] \
[number of views] [original poster] [---> + number in question <---] \
[Time of the last reply]
```

A screenshot:

[image: Google Groups]

I am concerned with the number following the name of each poster.

What does this number mean?

Comment: A screen shot would probably be more illustrative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gray number to the right of each poster's name is the amount of people who contributed to the thread, besides the original poster. Therefore, the original poster and (X) additional users contributed to each thread in the list.